# Disable whitespace highlighting for one filetype

Tags: vim

I highlight trailing whitespace for all files using this snippet in my `vimrc`:

```
hi link TrailingWhiteSpace Search
au BufWinEnter * let w:twsm=matchadd('TrailingWhiteSpace', '\s\+$')
" Setup a toggle.
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>w
  \ :if exists('w:twsm') <Bar>
  \   silent! call matchdelete(w:twsm) <Bar>
  \   unlet w:twsm <Bar>
  \ else <Bar>
  \   let w:twsm = matchadd('TrailingWhiteSpace', '\s\+$') <Bar>
  \ endif<CR>
```

However I'm also writing emails in Vim because I use Mutt and using [format=flowed](http://joeclark.org/ffaq.html) to avoid hard line breaks. I've set this in my `muttrc`

```
set text_flowed=yes
```

and have this in my `vimrc`

```
augroup ft_mail
    au!

    au FileType mail setlocal fo+=aw
augroup END
```

to achieve that.

This gives me visual line breaks in Vim but doesn't introduce hard line breaks in the actual emails. However this setup (and emails in general) tends to have trailing whitespace in various place, which I'm fine with, so I would prefer not to highlight it.

How can I stop trailing whitespace when writing emails? I'm open to better ways to highlight whitespace if that helps the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a buffer-local `b:IgnoreTrailingWhitespace` variable, set that in `~/.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim`, and consider it (via `exists('b:IgnoreTrailingWhitespace')` in your autocmds.

Alternatively, have a look at my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966); it has that functionality built in and even ships with an exception for the `mail` filetype (among others)!